# Is there any thing needed for https python web page

Tags: python, ssl

I been using python to create an web app and it has been doing well so far. Now I would like to encrypt the transmission of the data between client and server using https. The communication is generally just post form and web pages, no money transactions are involve.  Is there anything I need to change to the python code except setting the server up with certificate and configurate it to use https? I see a lot of information regarding ssl for python and I not sure if I need those modules and python setup to make https work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the ssl part for Python web app is managed by some frontend web server like `nginx`, `apache` or so.

This does not require any modification of your code (assuming, you are not expecting user to authenticate by ssl certificate on client side, what is quite exotic, but possible scenario).

If you want to run pure Python solution, I would recommend using `cherrypy`, which is able providing rather reliable and performant web server part (it will be very likely slower then served behind `nginx` or `apache`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Off topic question from you recommendation. I heard of web frame work such as django and cherrypy. I had been using the Python interpreter that came with the server. My web app had been working without calling any web framework. So what are they and how do they benefit me? Thanks

Comment: @user3014452 Plain Python (CGI, SimpleHTTPServer...) can serve web to very limited level, as you come to more complex services, further tools around will simplify your work. `Django` is most popular, provides database mapping, many supporting modules, templating, but impose on you large set of rules to follow. `CherryPy` is simple yet powerful, it lacks a bit good tutorials leading you to the result. `Flask` is my choice (for Python 2.7), great tooling, great tutorials, still having freedom to do it my way. There are many other frameworks around.